# target = "_blank" does not open in a new tab

Tags: html

```
<li class="parent">
    <a target="_blank" href="">For Doctors
        <i class="icon-chevron-small-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/video-consultation">Video Consultation</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.geniedocorbit.com">Orbit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cms">CMS</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It is not working in any browser the strange thing is even while pressing CTRL+button it's not opening in new tab

Comment: Works fine when I test it. I'm guessing you have some JavaScript (which you haven't included in your question, when creating an [mcve], make sure it does reproduce the problem) which is causing the problem.

Comment: Pop-up blocker? Unlikely, but still happens.

Comment: @Utkanos Nah, modern browsers should open in a new tab.

Comment: It works... here is my [fiddle proof](https://jsfiddle.net/xztsLby5/).